# WinError 10061 No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: python, sql, mysql

```
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="myusername", passwd="mypassword")

print(mydb)
```

> [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
>
> mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost:3306' (10061 No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it)

Comment: Did you tried to connect with your command line ? It looks like permission issue with your database/user.

Comment: Yes, I used command line

Comment: `actively refuses it` just means that there is nothing listening on given ip on given port

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/can-t-connect-to-mysql-server-on-ipaddress-10061

By default mysql doesn't allow users to be connected from outside localhost (loopback network interface), you need to enable it to work through all network interfaces.

modify the /etc/mysql/my.cnf

```
#default
#bind-address       = 127.0.0.1
#NEW
bind-address        = 0.0.0.0
```

then restart the service .
it only worked for my vagrant VM when I rebooted the VM.